# JMockit - Expectations - matching invocation of method that includes mocked object as argument

Tags: java, junit, mocking, jmockit, expectations

I am using JMockit to test an application (Java 8, Junit 4.12, JMockit 1.17).

I have some code which is supposed to upload some data to a list of endpoints.

The class that actually performs an upload to an endpoint is called PlatformDataUploader. This class has a method, called "upload", that performs a single "upload" to a single endpoint. This method takes the name of the destination (which is a two character string, and the object to be uploaded). Based on the name of the destination, it constructs the URL that the data should be sent to.

I would like to create a test that simply confirms that, when the application is executed, the upload method of PlatformDataUploader is called the expected number of times (7 times, because the application is currently configured to upload data to 7 endpoints). I would like to confirm that the destination string that is passed to the upload method is the expected one, but I dont care about the data that is sent (represented by an instance of PlatformInstallationData).

A simplified version of the application code is the following:

```
 ...

 private boolean uploadToServices(final List<String> serviceNames) {

    boolean allGood = true;

    PlatformDataUploader platformDataUploader = new PlatformDataUploader();

    for (String serviceName : serviceNames) {

        LOG.info("Attempting to upload to " + serviceName + "...");

        // construct object to send
        PlatformInstallationData platformInstallationData = new PlatformInstallationData();

        ...
        // code here that adds content to platformInstallationData
        ...

        // send object to endpoint of this service
        allGood = allGood &&
            platformDataUploader.upload(serviceName, platformInstallationData);
    }

    return allGood;
}
```

A simplified version of the test code is the following:

```
@Test
public void whenUploadThenExpectedCallsToUploader(@Mocked final PlatformDataUploader platformDataUploader,
        @Mocked final PlatformInstallationData platformInstallationData)
                throws IOException {

    UploaderApplication target = new UploaderApplication();

    new Expectations() {
        {
            platformDataUploader.upload("AP", platformInstallationData);
            result = true;
            times = 1;

            platformDataUploader.upload("VV", platformInstallationData);
            result = true;
            times = 1;
            ...
            THE REST OF THE EXPECTED CALLS 
            ...


        }
    };

    target.execute(params);
}
```

When I execute the test I get: "mockit.internal.MissingInvocation: Missing 1 invocation". It refers to the first line in the expectations that I have defined.

The problem seems to be that the second argument in the upload method, which is a mocked PlatformInstallationData, does not match the instance that is created in the application code (even though that instance should also be mocked).

To try to understand what is happening, I have done a test where I removed the second argument from the upload method (from the application code and from the test code), therefore it only had to match a string, such as "AP" against the string that exists within the application at that point, and in that case it matched correctly. So I know that, using this approach, it can match a string correctly, but it fails to match the mocked PlatformInstallationData object.

I am surprised by this behaviour, as I felt sure that I had previously been able to create expectations that include mocked objects as method arguments, and I thought that it matched them correctly.

Can anyone please explain this behaviour, and possibly suggest how this should be tested. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way of writing the test so that it matches the calls, and it confirms that the expected number of calls are made to the upload method, and that the expected Strings are passed as the first argument. I used the "any" placeholder for the second argument. It is a little ugly, because I have to do a cast. As shown below:

```
@Test
public void whenUploadThenExpectedCallsToUploader(@Mocked final PlatformDataUploader platformDataUploader,
        @Mocked final PlatformInstallationData platformInstallationData)
                throws IOException {

    InstallPlatformCommand target = new InstallPlatformCommand(Action.INSTALL_PLATFORM);

    new Expectations() {
        {
            platformDataUploader.upload("AP", (PlatformInstallationData) any);
            result = true;
            times = 1;

            platformDataUploader.upload("VV", (PlatformInstallationData) any);
            result = true;
            times = 1;

            ...
            The rest of the expected calls
            ...
        }
    };

    target.execute(params);
}
```

I am sure there are other ways of doing it. If you have a cleaner way, then please let me know.

Comment: You probably don't need to mock `PlatformInstallationData`, so I would remove that mock parameter. An alternative to `(X) any` is to use `withInstanceOf(PlatformInstallationData.class)`. Finally, you could capture the sequence of values passed to the "serviceName" parameter into a local list by using `withCapture(List<String>)`, and later comparing it to the input list with `assertEquals`; this would allow the test to record a single expectation for the `upload` method.